# Blank Line after \myequations

Tags: equations

I'm using \myequation, but is being inserted blank line after, what can I do to solve?

Thanks

Example in LaTeX:

```
%%Preamble
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%Equations
\usepackage{tocloft} 
\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\listofmyequations

\chapter{}

\begin{equation}  \label{eq:mlmM} 
y_i = X_i\beta + Z_i\gamma_i + \varepsilon_i
\end{equation} 
\myequations{Generalized Linear Mixed Models}

$$\begin{cases}
\gamma_i \sim N_q(0,\psi)\\
\varepsilon_i \sim N_n(0,\sigma^2\wedge _i)
\end{cases}$$\\

\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `$$...$$`, that is deprecated syntax. Use `\[...\]` instead, Also the `\\` after `$$` is pretty useless

Comment: In addition, I don't see a blank line

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a different approach.

First of all, never use `$$` in LaTeX. Second, never have two consecutive displays: use `gather` or `align`.

The `\myequations` command should be, with this code, *inside* the equation, be it `equation`, `align` or `gather`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\listequationsname}{List of Equations}
\newlistof{myequations}{equ}{\listequationsname}
\setlength{\cftmyequationsnumwidth}{2.5em}

\makeatletter
\appto{\endequation}{\myequations@hook\gdef\myequations@hook{}}
\appto{\endalign}{\myequations@hook\gdef\myequations@hook{}}
\appto{\endgather}{\myequations@hook\gdef\myequations@hook{}}
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
  \ifmeasuring@\else
    \gappto\myequations@hook{%
      \vadjust{%
        \addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}%
      }%
    }%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\listofmyequations

\chapter{Title}

\lipsum*[2]
\begin{equation}
y_i = X_i\beta + Z_i\gamma_i + \varepsilon_i
\label{eq:1} 
\myequations{Attempt}
\end{equation}
\lipsum*[2]
\begin{gather}
y_i = X_i\beta + Z_i\gamma_i + \varepsilon_i
\label{eq:mlmM} 
\myequations{Generalized Linear Mixed Models}
\\
\begin{cases}
\gamma_i \sim N_q(0,\psi)\\
\varepsilon_i \sim N_n(0,\sigma^2\wedge _i)
\notag
\end{cases}
\end{gather}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to remove some white space. But you are inserting it manually using that command.

```
\newcommand{\myequations}[1]{%
\addcontentsline{equ}{myequations}{\protect\numberline{\theequation}#1}\par}
```

This ends with `\par`. Just remove that and you have some white space less.